# Datetime - set seconds to 00

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

My problem is that when I'm trying to set todays date time to 00:00:00 I'm getting some weird decimal number as a seconds. Why is that happening and what is it? And how can I get rid of that decimal?

This is what I get:

```
2017-06-20 00:00:00.652698+00:00
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

```
2017-06-20 00:00:00+00:00
```

**code**:

```
todays_date = timezone.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)

print(todays_date)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `timezone.now().date()` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, I need to have time too, and date() is creating only a date without a time. Anyways, thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Sure, but `datetime.combine(timezone.now().date(), time.min)` could give you that too ;-)

Comment: Title is misleading

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`datetime.datetime` supports *microsecond* precision. To truncate the fractional seconds, add `microsecond=0` to your `replace` call:

```
todays_date = timezone.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
print(todays_date)
```

Or you can get just the date part as a `datetime.date` object with the `date` method:

```
todays_date = timezone.now().date()
print(todays_date)
```

which shall output

```
2017-06-20
```